# Jenkins complains with "Couldn't clean up oid" at the end of a build

Tags: jenkins

I'm playing around with Jenkins (version 1.650) and have successfully set up a job that builds a Maven based Java project. However, at the end of most builds, I get a warning, that clean up failed. The build still succeeds.

```
[WARNING] Couldn't clean up oid=3 from null
    hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: channel is already closed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.send(Channel.java:578)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$PhantomReferenceImpl.cleanup(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:360)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$PhantomReferenceImpl.access$700(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:319)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$Unexporter.run(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:420)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1163)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1138)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1079)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
```

As I only now Jenkins as a enduser I don't exactly know what's going on at that point. I've been looking around but can't find any useful hints that point me to a solution. I only have a master node setup, no slaves involved, so I don't understand how the remoting comes into play here.

I'm running Jenkins on a Vagrant managed VM with Ubuntu 14.04. My job pulls in a project from Bitbucket using a ssh connection. But that's all probably not too important in this context.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am getting this, too....

Comment: Not really. At some point this stopped happening, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: I realized now, the job actually goes green even when you get this stack-trace... it actually says "warning", so no big deal then :) ----- EDIT: and now the warning disappeared here, too :)

Comment: Right, it was a cosmetic problem for me, too... Still quite annoying.

Comment: It seems happens not only on build, I got the same error when I import one of my job from XML, the job is imported, but I got this error at the end

Answer (score 2):

To summarize:

It's just a warning --- you can ignore it.

Then it will go away after a while :)

Comment: Right, I'll be keeping my question open, though, as I'd be interested in the actual root cause and a proper solution... :)

Comment: SEVERE: Couldn't clean up oid=2 from null <- This is NOT just a warning.

Comment: Says WARNING, not SEVERE, in the OP above.
Maybe you are having a different error?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have this issue. I had this issue when I performed maven task from the `<plugin />` part.

For me it is resolved when I enable `process plugins during pom parsing` at the build-attempt options. Hope it helps.